# How does the stomach differentiate between liquids and solids to initiate churning?

Tags: human-physiology

Or maybe it doesn't at all. Can the stomach tell the difference between liquids and solids and change its churning process accordingly despite that it has no nerves? Because liquids don't need to be churned, so I figure there's a chance animals, or at least humans, evolved in such a way that the stomach wouldn't waste the energy trying to do it.

Comment: "...despite that it has no nerves" Why do you think that?

Comment: Because there are very very very very very very few cases where people generally "feel" anything they have eaten in their stomach in any way, shape or form. Of course, it still has neurons that transmit signals for motility and secretion.

Comment: So, simply because you believe that, you state it as a fact? To use your words, there are very very very very very very many cases where people generally "feel"stuffed they have eaten a Thanksgiving meal. Your stomach isn't 'wired' to feel like your fingers. But it has plenty of a variety of afferent neurons.

Comment: I don't need to believe anything, it's a commonly held fact that there are no "nerves" in the stomach. The "feeling" from turkey has nothing to do with any nerves in the stomach, it's commonly known that not only does meat take a lot of energy to digest, but tryptophan also contributes to sleepiness.

Comment: It's also a commonly *known* fact among scientists that most people don't know much of anything about human anatomy and physiology. You are living proof. I didn't say anything about sleepiness, and if you want real "facts", look up *orexin/hypocretin*. Also see [**this**](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27019197) for afferent nerves of the stomach.  You should quit while you're only behind to an acceptable degree. Keep showing off your "commonly held facts" and you'll only come out more behind.

Comment: Also, just ask yourself: if your stomach has no (afferent) nerves, why  do ulcers hurt? Why do antacids (like Mylanta) help?

Comment: Subjective opinions aren't commonly known among scientists because opinions such as yours aren't science. Humans don't have somatic receptors like nociceptors in the stomach. You have the legal right to pretend whatever you want, but your article doesn't disprove that, viscera only encompass the area around organs, they are not the organs themselves, and viscera are sensitive to things like stretching and inflammation, that's why ulcers hurt.

Comment: How about you ask yourself why you're so desperate to feel superior to other people? What shortcomings have you made of your own life that lead to be that desperate? At this point it's obvious you're just a troll.

Comment: @VaneVoe Please watch your tone. As I already said in your other question, writing answer is voluntary. With this kind of behaviour you will not attract anybody to spend time writing an answer.

Comment: @Chris Actual experts have expertise for the benefit of society. If these self-proclaimed stackexchange "experts" are so childish as to impede the assistance of potentially hundreds of viewers over their own childish, arbitrary whims, then they were never experts in the first place and their words were never worth regarding. Remember that it is your site that brags about experts answering questions Chris, so I expect to see questions answered if no one is lying about the presence of experts. Otherwise, the site should reevaluate its false-advertising campaign.

Comment: @VaneVoe Nope, you are wrong. We don't have to - we can.

Comment: @Chris Other than the fact that it literally says "expert communities" on the stack home site, you only don't have to if and only if the site is fraudulent, if there aren't actual experts here. Otherwise, if there are, then the question will be answered. You can say there are experts all you want, but the more the question goes unanswered, the more and more evidence there is that you too are a fraud.

Comment: @VaneVoe One last time: Your attitude is one of the problems. EOD

Comment: It's clear that I am teaching you some science (you read an abstract and learned some things) but not enough, e.g. you state, "...viscera only encompass the area around organs, they are not the organs themselves..." however, the actual definition follows: vis·cer·aˈ, visərə/ noun: *the internal organs in the main cavities of the body, especially those in the abdomen, e.g., the intestines.* (emphasis mine) I'm done here too.

Comment: You're not trying to teach anything because you're too busy trying to pat yourself on the back. Neither somatic nor visceral pain are perceived within the organs, only in the areas around. When people have heart attacks, does their heart hurt? Nope, that's why people report "chest" pain and not "heart" pain. Your arrogance defeated you before you even arrived, you were already done.

Comment: Confirmed: there are no experts here, or such a simple question would have been answered, which means stackexchange is false-advertising when it claims experts reside here.

Comment: Tbh I'd like this question to be answered but I can see now no one would even bother.Man,why fight over stuff? I daresay youre the one in wrong when you said it had no nerves but anyways this is a really good question. How does the stomach differentiate between liquid and solid food?And what bout semi solid food?

Comment: No one is fighting over anything, if you choose to argue instead of answering, then you can only inevitably be the problem you complain about. Clearly stackexchange only cares about having self-absorbed excuses to pat itself on the back rather than contributing to humanity which is not the mark of an expert. Stackexchange has had every opportunity to prove me wrong and yet has failed to do so. The fact that such a simple question is still unanswered despite that an actual credible graduate has already answered it proves me right.